# Unable to store session in Database in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I recently upgraded my application from laravel 5.1 to 5.2 version. Also I am trying to store session in Database which is currently stored in file.

I have changed .env file to include SESSION_DRIVER=database. Also I have changed session.config file to include 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database') and generated required session table.

But when I tried to login to the application I am getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67: If I change SESSION_DRIVER=file then application is working as expected.

But this was not the case in Laravel 5.1 version.

What is changed in Laravel 5.2 version and what steps are required to store user session in database?

Comment: Try clean your cache and cookies after you change the driver to **database**.

Comment: Did you create session table?

Comment: @TheFallen I cleared cache & cookies but no luck.  I created session table.

Comment: Try to debug by outputting `\Session::get('_token');` and compare it with both tokens from this method `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` @ line 107

Answer (score 4):

I had to deal with this issue myself as well. So the initial steps are as you had already mentioned in your question.

- On fresh install of laravel and verify that everything works, change the `SESSION_DRIVER=file` to `SESSION_DRIVER=database`
- Run the following commands IN ORDER in your console within the directory of your app:

  ```
  php artisan session:table
  composer dump-autoload
  php artisan migrate
  ```
- **(This step might be different from what you did)** In your config\session.php file search for:

  ```
  'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
  ```

  and change it to the following

  ```
  'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'app.database'),
  ```
- Within the same config\session.php file change the encrypt configuration to `true`
- Set your connection and table name settings appropriately

  ```
   'connection' => 'database_name_here',
   'table' => 'sessions', //here you can change but sessions is recommended until you get more comfortable with how it all works
  ```
- Attempt to login to your application and check your database to see if it all works.

If more help is needed you can also check a few resources that have helped me solve the issue. Keep in mind these resources are of people having similar issues but maybe your problem is similar to theirs. Only way to find out is to investigate. Hope this helps! =) :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-store-users-id-in-session-table-laravel-5

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session

(Video tutorial on Laravel Sessions, VERY good place to help you get to where you need to be!)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FMecyZs5Cg

Answer (score -1):

look it's ok to go with it manual but why don't u use the `php artisan make:auth`
it creates every thing u need for authentication and also helps u keeping the session instead of doing it manual ?

Comment: If I use php artisan make:auth, then I will not able to use my customized authentication. I just want to user session in Database and to track user login & logout time.

Comment: i know u will not use your authentication , i mean it will build anything instead of u and u can also track whatever u want with it just as u r building it