# Store session details in database laravel-neo4j

Tags: laravel, docker, neo4j, neo4jphp, neoeloquent

Hello everyone,

I am new to `neo4j`. I have built a test app. It is a simple `laravel-neo4j` user login and register app. Everything works fine. But I want to store the session details in the database, not in the file. So I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439721/unable-to-store-session-in-database-in-laravel-5-2/39240363#39240363) method and got the `Undefined offset: 0` error. So please help me. I have given the link for docker and commands to run it. Please run this and help me to solve this problem. Right now the session is storing in the file. First, register an account then use that account for login. Thank you.

docker: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q0Cd6QwaVnqyoWeUOHWnodWNCL24MBrj/view?usp=sharing

**Command to run docker file**

```
./docker_compose.sh build
./docker_compose.sh up
```

**URLs**

Front-end: http://0.0.0.0:8081/

Login: http://0.0.0.0:8081/login

Register: http://0.0.0.0:8081/register

Neo4j: http://0.0.0.0:8083/browser/

**Login credentials for neo4j:**

```
Username: neo4j
Password: root
```